# Locks on updating rows with foreign key constraint

Tags: postgresql, locking

I tried executing the same `UPDATE` query twice like below.

First time the transaction has no lock but I can see a row lock after second query.

Schema:

```
test=# \d t1
                 Table "public.t1"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 i      | integer |           | not null | 
 j      | integer |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "t1_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (i)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "t2" CONSTRAINT "t2_j_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (j) REFERENCES t1(i)

test=# \d t2
                 Table "public.t2"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 i      | integer |           | not null | 
 j      | integer |           |          | 
 k      | integer |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "t2_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (i)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "t2_j_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (j) REFERENCES t1(i)
```

Existing data:

```
test=# SELECT * FROM t1 ORDER BY i;
 i | j 
---+---
 1 | 1
 2 | 2
(2 rows)

test=# SELECT * FROM t2 ORDER BY i;
 i | j | k 
---+---+---
 3 | 1 |  
 4 | 2 |  
(2 rows)
```

UPDATE queries and row lock status:

```
test=# BEGIN;
BEGIN
test=# UPDATE t2 SET k = 123 WHERE i = 3;
UPDATE 1
test=# SELECT * FROM t1 AS t, pgrowlocks('t1') AS p WHERE p.locked_row = t.ctid;
 i | j | locked_row | locker | multi | xids | modes | pids 
---+---+------------+--------+-------+------+-------+------
(0 rows)

test=# UPDATE t2 SET k = 123 WHERE i = 3;
UPDATE 1
test=# SELECT * FROM t1 AS t, pgrowlocks('t1') AS p WHERE p.locked_row = t.ctid;
 i | j | locked_row | locker | multi |   xids   |       modes       | pids 
---+---+------------+--------+-------+----------+-------------------+------
 1 | 1 | (0,1)      | 107239 | f     | {107239} | {"For Key Share"} | {76}
(1 row)

test=#
```

Why does postgres try to get a row lock only on second time?

By the way, queries updating column t2.j create new lock (ForKeyShare) on t1 row at once. This behavior make sense because t2.j has foreign key constraint references t1.i. But the queries above seems not.

Does anyone can explain this lock?

PostgreSQL version: 9.6.3

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I got it.

https://engineering.nordeus.com/postgres-locking-revealed/

> This is optimization that exists in Postgres. If locking manager can figure out from the first query that foreign key is not changed (it is not mentioned in update query or is set to same value) it will not lock parent table. But in second query it will behave as it is described in documentation (it will lock parent table in ROW SHARE locking mode and referenced row in FOR SHARE mode)

It seems MySQL is wiser about foreign key locks because the same `UPDATE` query doesn't make such locks on MySQL.

Comment: Why do you think the ROW SHARE lock is a problem?

Comment: Unnecessary locks make lower performance because of lock conflicts and in my case it had been causing deadlocks. Of course, I know multiple UPDATEs on the same row in one transaction is not good and proper using of explicit locks can reduce deadlock risks. In my case the deadlocks happened TPC-C performance test created not by myself. I wanted to know why only PostgreSQL behaves like this.

Comment: The Row Share on T1 does not prevent updates (or selects) on that row. It only prevents DELETEs on that row. So I don't understand how that could lead to a deadlock. Plus deadlocks are a sign of wrong transaction handling in the _application_, not a problem in the database. But if you want to know the reasoning or technical details you should ask this on the [postgres mailing list](https://www.postgresql.org/list/pgsql-general/).

Comment: I expect Postgres behaves like that. But the referenced row on T1 is locked using FOR KEY SHARE mode and this lock mode prevents `SELECT FOR UPDATE` on the same row. So deadlocks can happen, only on Postgres. But I know the way to avoid it. `SELECT FOR NO KEY UPDATE` doesn't make conflicts with `FOR KEY SHARE`. Anyway thanks your advice.